# First argument is not an open RODBC channel on IDEAR tool

Tags: r, azure, github, yaml, utilities

I am having this problem. I want to use the IDEAR tool on my SQL Server Database. I run the IDEAR code Github provided on RStudio and select the YAML file I created in order to connect to my database. After selecting the file I get the following error:

> Error: first argument is not an open RODBC channel

When I try to run a YAML file the tool provided as example, I get no error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I will post my YAML code here:

```
DataSource:
    SQLServer
Server:
    ORD02984\SQL2016
Database:
    Computed
Username:
    Steve
Password:
    *********
Query:
    select * from dbo.AirOnTime
```

Note: I put stars as password just to show it here

---

IDEAR tool: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-TDSP-Utilities/blob/master/DataScienceUtilities/DataReport-Utils/R/team-data-science-process-idear-instructions.md

Comment: I think we need to see your code in order to be helpful here.

Comment: Sure, this is the code provided on Github: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-TDSP-Utilities/blob/master/DataScienceUtilities/DataReport-Utils/R/Run-IDEAR.R

Comment: This looks more like a DB connection error than a YAML error. I don't know any of the involved technologies apart from YAML, but you may want to ensure that `ORD02984\SQL2016` is a correct value for the server.

Comment: I checked all my parameters and they are all correct. ORD02984\SQL2016 is the value for the server. I don't know what's going wrong here..